# Database ER diagram not showing relationships even though specified

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have created a sqlite database. Even though I have included the the relationship between the primary and foreign keys, when I am generating the ER diagram I am not able to see the connections between them. I am using datagrip to create the diagram. I tested other databases in datagrip and dbvisualizer and i do not have any problems with them but only in this.

ER diagram -

[image: er diagram]

This is the script i used for creating two tables in the database -

```
def create_titles_table():
    # connect to the database
    conn = sqlite3.connect("imdb.db")
    # create a cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    print()
    print("Creating titles table...")
    c.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titles
                (titleId  TEXT NOT NULL, titleType  TEXT, 
                primaryTitle  TEXT, originalTitle  TEXT,
                isAdult  INTEGER, startYear  REAL, 
                endYear  REAL, runtimeMinutes REAL,
                PRIMARY KEY (titleId)
                )
    """
    )
    # commit changes
    conn.commit()

    # read the title data
    df = load_data("title.basics.tsv")
    # replace \N with nan
    df.replace("\\N", np.nan, inplace=True)
    # rename columns
    df.rename(columns={"tconst": "titleId"}, inplace=True)
    # drop the genres column
    title_df = df.drop("genres", axis=1)
    # convert the data types from str to numeric
    title_df["startYear"] = pd.to_numeric(title_df["startYear"], errors="coerce")
    title_df["endYear"] = pd.to_numeric(title_df["endYear"], errors="coerce")
    title_df["runtimeMinutes"] = pd.to_numeric(
        title_df["runtimeMinutes"], errors="coerce"
    )

    # insert the data into titles table
    title_df.to_sql("titles", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)

    # commit changes
    conn.commit()
    # close the connection
    conn.close()
    print("Completed!")
    print()


def create_ratings_table():
# connect to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect("imdb.db")
# create a cursor
c = conn.cursor()

print()
print("Creating ratings table...")
c.execute(
    """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratings 
            (titleId  TEXT NOT NULL, averageRating  REAL, numVotes  INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY (titleId) REFERENCES titles(titleId)
            )
"""
)
# commit changes
conn.commit()

# read the data
df = load_data("title.ratings.tsv")
df.rename(columns={"tconst": "titleId"}, inplace=True)

# insert the data into the ratings table
df.to_sql("ratings", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)

# commit changes
conn.commit()
# close the connection
conn.close()
print("Completed!")
print()
```

Can anyone tell me where am i making the mistake?

Comment: How exactly do you create the diagram?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I  right clicked on the database in datagrip then selected  diagram > show visualisation and save it from there.